# How does Flush error occur and how do I solve it?

Tags: python, authentication, flask, sqlalchemy, flush

I'm trying to make a login page I have been trying for weeks but this error keeps popping up:
`sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError: Instance <Users at 0x10bd8c580> has a NULL identity key.`

The error lies in the `register.py` file. Apparently flask doesn't like me using `.commit()` or `.add()`. I've also tried to use `.flush`
but it gave me the same error still

`register.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint, url_for, render_template, redirect, request
from flask_login import LoginManager
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
import sqlalchemy
from models import db, Users

register = Blueprint('register', __name__, template_folder='../frontend')
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(register)

@register.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def show():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        confirm_password = request.form['confirm-password']

        if username and email and password and confirm_password:
            if password == confirm_password:
                hashed_password = generate_password_hash(
                    password, method='sha256')
                try:
                    new_user = Users(
                        username=username,
                        email=email,
                        password=hashed_password,
                    )

                    db.session.add(new_user)
                    db.session.commit()
                except sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError:
                    return redirect(url_for('register.show') + '?error=user-or-email-exists')

                return redirect(url_for('login.show') + '?success=account-created')
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('register.show') + '?error=missing-fields')
    else:
        return render_template('register.html')
```

`Models.py`:

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Users(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String)
    item = db.Column(db.String(25))
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

I'm still a beginner with flask so excuse me if it's real obvious, any assistance would be very welcome!

Comment: Does your model have an `__init__` method?  If it does, please [edit] the question to show it.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what sql database you are using with sqlAlchemy. Anyways, the id is not being generated so the new_user has no identity. that's why your getting this error. To solve the problem modify your model as follows:

```
class Users(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String)
    item = db.Column(db.String(25))
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

or you can use Sequence instead of autoincrement:

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, Sequence('user_seq'))
```

This is for the identity issue, but note that you need to specify user_loader for flask_login to work.

Comment: For the OP's model, `primary_key=True` is enough to automatically trigger auto-increment behaviour - see [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html?highlight=autoincrement#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.autoincrement).

Comment: First of all, you can't use autoincrement with an integer column and when I put it in another column like `username` it gives me the same error: `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.FlushError: Instance <Users at 0x10a05e820> has a NULL identity key.` Secondly, When I tried your second solution it gave me a syntaxerror and when I searched it up you apparenty don't need `Sequence`. Do you know what else it might be? thanks!

Comment: Exactly like @snakecharmerb said, might you have a solution for this?